# How to connect to GoodData ADS using Microsoft .NET

Tags: c#, .net, jdbc, gooddata, cloud-connect

We have an emerging need to modify the schema in our Agile Data Warehouse including adding new tables. We've been able to manually connect to the ADS database using Squirrel SQL and CloudConnect.

However, we would like a way to automate this process so that we can ensure that the schema remains consistent between our development, test and production ADS instances.

We're a .NET shop and most of our code is in C#. Has anyone had any success connecting directly to ADS using .NET (C# or VB)?

I've looked at trying to use the GoodData JDBC driver but it looks like referencing a JDBC driver from .NET is not particularly straight-forward and there is not a GoodData ODBC or ADO.NET driver available.

I'd rather use something like the Vertica driver for ADO.NET available at https://my.vertica.com/vertica-client-drivers/ however, I'm not sure what to use for all of the [connection properties](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/ConnectingToHPVertica/ClientADO/ADO.NETConnectionProperties.htm).  I've attempted to connect using the Host and Port that are returned from the DW connection endpoints API but receive the following error: "SSL Startup Failed." when using the Vertica ADO.NET driver.

Is there a way to connect to the GoodData ADS daatabase using .NET or any better approaches to modifying the ADS schema using a CloudConnect graph or REST API?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: All the methods I know to connect to ADS use either JDBC driver or Cloudconnect. What would you want to do that is not possible with Cloudconnect? python automation (via JDBC) is also ridiculously easy in the far-fetched case where it could be of any use to you

Answer (score 0):

GoodData currently provides only a custom JDBC driver for connecting to ADS. Standard Vertica drivers cannot be used. See https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Data+Warehouse+Technology

It is not possible to use the JDBC driver in .NET for obvious reasons. Theoretically it could be possible to use a ODBC-JDBC gateway, but I have not tested this solution. Also there is JVM implementation for .NET, but I have not tested it also. It is http://www.ikvm.net/.

So the easiest way is really to use CloudConnect or a SQL client which supports JDBC drivers. For automating a process the easiest ways are probably Java or JRuby.